# SQL Server Profiler do not trace all Entity Framework 4 queries - issue

Tags: .net, linq, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I'm reading through [Programming Entity Framework, 2nd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596807252.do), and in first chapter there is a very simple query:

```
    private static void QueryContacts()
    {
        using (var context = new SampleEntities())
        {
            var contacts = context.Contacts.Where(c => c.FirstName == "Robert");
            var res = (contacts as ObjectQuery<Contact>).Execute(MergeOption.NoTracking);

            foreach (var contact in res)
            {
                foreach (var address in contact.Addresses)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", address.City);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.Write("Press Enter...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

When I attached SQL profiler to database instance I can see that following SQL was executed:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ContactID] AS [ContactID], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Extent1].[AddDate] AS [AddDate], 
[Extent1].[ModifiedDate] AS [ModifiedDate]
FROM [dbo].[Contact] AS [Extent1]
WHERE N'Robert' = [Extent1].[FirstName]
```

but there is no sign of quering Address table (even though there are addresses).

When I attached Entity Framework Profiler I could see both:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[ContactID]    AS [ContactID],
       [Extent1].[FirstName]    AS [FirstName],
       [Extent1].[LastName]     AS [LastName],
       [Extent1].[Title]        AS [Title],
       [Extent1].[AddDate]      AS [AddDate],
       [Extent1].[ModifiedDate] AS [ModifiedDate]
FROM   [dbo].[Contact] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  N'Robert' = [Extent1].[FirstName]
```

and

```
SELECT [Extent1].[addressID]     AS [addressID],
       [Extent1].[Street1]       AS [Street1],
       [Extent1].[Street2]       AS [Street2],
       [Extent1].[City]          AS [City],
       [Extent1].[StateProvince] AS [StateProvince],
       [Extent1].[CountryRegion] AS [CountryRegion],
       [Extent1].[PostalCode]    AS [PostalCode],
       [Extent1].[AddressType]   AS [AddressType],
       [Extent1].[ContactID]     AS [ContactID],
       [Extent1].[ModifiedDate]  AS [ModifiedDate]
FROM   [dbo].[Address] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  [Extent1].[ContactID] = 209 /* @EntityKeyValue1 */
```

Do you know what is happening with SQL Server Profiler so that is doesn't catch queries to Address table?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure that you don't have any filter set in SQL profiler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bingo!

I've selected all event types and it turned out that Addresses query was tracable as RPC:Completed, whereas Contact was tracable as SQL:BatchCompleted:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[addressID] AS [addressID], 
[Extent1].[Street1] AS [Street1], 
[Extent1].[Street2] AS [Street2], 
[Extent1].[City] AS [City], 
[Extent1].[StateProvince] AS [StateProvince], 
[Extent1].[CountryRegion] AS [CountryRegion], 
[Extent1].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], 
[Extent1].[AddressType] AS [AddressType], 
[Extent1].[ContactID] AS [ContactID], 
[Extent1].[ModifiedDate] AS [ModifiedDate]
FROM [dbo].[Address] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[ContactID] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=220
```

Comment: And *why* are [certain] queries executed through RPC and sp_execsql? :>

Answer (score 0):

Addresses are queried during lazy loading inside you loop. It will be more efficient to fetch them in single shoot with Contacts. To do so you will need:

```
var res = (contacts as ObjectQuery<Contact>).Include("Addresses").Execute(MergeOption.NoTracking);
```

Comment: Hi, I inferred that adresses are lazy loaded, I haven't got to that controlling that feature in EF4 though. This is why I launched SQL Server Profiler in the first place, to see how it handles addresses.

Comment: So if you are walking through you loop in debugger Profiler still doesn't catch anything? If so then it definitely has something to do with filters. Another possible reason - that Contact with this ID already materialized in Context and its addresses has been loaded also. In such case you will get yours address from Context without query to DB.